# result of sum of 2 objects of classes keep showing up zero

Tags: c++, class, oop, operator-overloading

I have added up two objects of same class using operator overloading and stored their result in another function but when I try to print their sum the result is always zero

```
distance distance::operator+(const distance &obj)
{
    distance temp;
    temp.inches = inches + obj.inches;
    return temp;
}

void distance::output()
{
    std::cout<<inches<<std::endl;
}



sum=far+near;
std::cout<<"sum: ";
sum.output();
std::cout<<"\n";
```

note: sum, far, near are objects of class

in main declaration of objects

```
distance far, near, sum, diff;
```

Comment: Not enough code showing. Can't tell how far and near are defined, or how your class is constructed for them. Why not also show the result of `near.output()` and `far.output()`? How do we know those aren't 0?

Comment: please show a [mre]